# How to remove rows that have all NULL values

Tags: sql-server

How can I remove the null rows in the table?

[image]

I've written a query to join several columns from different tables (It works). However, there are many null rows at the bottom of the table which I would like to remove.

```
SELECT  
s.Name_of_owner, 
s.pos, 
s.Orientation,
isnull(s.DBName,z.DBName) DBName,
isnull (s.Name,z.Name) Name,
isnull (s.Refno,z.Refno) Refno,
isnull (s.Type_,z.Type_) Type_,
isnull (s.Desc_,z.Desc_) Desc_,
isnull (s.mcount, z.mcount) mcount,
z.Name_of_Site,
z.Desc_of_Site
FROM SITE s  
FULL OUTER JOIN ZONE z ON z.Name = s.Name 
FULL OUTER JOIN SITE ON z.DBName = s.DBName
```

Comment: `where myfield is not null`?

Comment: btw - you don't have an alias for your second join - does that matter?

Comment: @DaleBurrell myfield?

Comment: A field of your choosing which is indicative of the row being null.

Comment: `there are many null rows` are you *absolutely certain? If a full join returns a row it means there *was* a row either on the left or the right. You'll never get all nulls. Unless of course, that row actually contained NULL values. Add all join fields in the results to see *which* table actually produced those rows

Comment: @Ken your query would return nulls if there *were* matching rows in Zone and Site, whose `Name_of_Site` and `Desc_of_Site` fields contained nulls.

Comment: Do you want to remove those rows from query result or to permanently delete them from source tables (`delete from size`, `delete from zone`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` as `inner join` matches tables on existing values:

```
SELECT  
s.Name_of_owner, 
s.pos, 
s.Orientation,
isnull(s.DBName,z.DBName) DBName,
isnull (s.Name,z.Name) Name,
isnull (s.Refno,z.Refno) Refno,
isnull (s.Type_,z.Type_) Type_,
isnull (s.Desc_,z.Desc_) Desc_,
isnull (s.mcount, z.mcount) mcount,
z.Name_of_Site,
z.Desc_of_Site
FROM SITE s  
INNER JOIN ZONE z ON z.Name = s.Name 
INNER JOIN SITE ON z.DBName = s.DBName
```

Comment: what is fallback value

Comment: it displays the name of the columns only but no data

Comment: @ken, do you mean that there is no data output now with `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `WHERE` filter:

```
SELECT  
    s.Name_of_owner, 
    s.pos, 
    s.Orientation,
    isnull(s.DBName,z.DBName) DBName,
    isnull (s.Name,z.Name) Name,
    isnull (s.Refno,z.Refno) Refno,
    isnull (s.Type_,z.Type_) Type_,
    isnull (s.Desc_,z.Desc_) Desc_,
    isnull (s.mcount, z.mcount) mcount,
    z.Name_of_Site,
    z.Desc_of_Site
FROM 
    SITE s  
    FULL OUTER JOIN ZONE z ON z.Name = s.Name 
    FULL OUTER JOIN SITE ON z.DBName = s.DBName
WHERE
    s.Name_of_owner IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to make sure that all columns are not `NULL`, then you will have to write a bunch of `AND` filters:

```
SELECT  
    s.Name_of_owner, 
    s.pos, 
    s.Orientation,
    isnull(s.DBName,z.DBName) DBName,
    isnull (s.Name,z.Name) Name,
    isnull (s.Refno,z.Refno) Refno,
    isnull (s.Type_,z.Type_) Type_,
    isnull (s.Desc_,z.Desc_) Desc_,
    isnull (s.mcount, z.mcount) mcount,
    z.Name_of_Site,
    z.Desc_of_Site
FROM 
    SITE s  
    FULL OUTER JOIN ZONE z ON z.Name = s.Name 
    FULL OUTER JOIN SITE ON z.DBName = s.DBName
WHERE
    s.Name_of_owner IS NOT NULL AND
    s.pos IS NOT NULL AND
    (S.DBName IS NOT NULL OR z.DBName IS NOT NULL) AND -- isnull(s.DBName,z.DBName)
    -- ....
```

Keep in mind that you are using `FULL JOIN`, so there might be complete tables that yield `NULL` values when they don't match. So forcing a filter on a particular column (from a particular table) *might* remove rows from other "full joined" tables. You can do the `OR` filter to check for values in multiple tables (as this example).